# Spark app can run in standalone mode but can't run in yarn cluster

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

En, hello everyone a quest troubled me a long time. I can run my spark app in standalone mode by this command
`spark-submit --master spark://fuxiuyin-virtual-machine:7077 test_app.py`
But this app fail to run in yarn cluster by this command
`spark-submit --master yarn test_app.py`

I think my yarn cluster is healthy.
The output of `jps` is

```
$ jps
8289 Worker
14882 NameNode
15475 ResourceManager
8134 Master
15751 NodeManager
15063 DataNode
17212 Jps
15295 SecondaryNameNode
```

And the 'Nodes of the cluster' page is
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BckFN.png)

The output of `spark-submit` is

```
$ /opt/spark/bin/spark-submit --master yarn test_app.py
16/10/28 16:54:39 INFO spark.SparkContext: Running Spark version 2.0.1
16/10/28 16:54:39 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/10/28 16:54:39 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: fuxiuyin
16/10/28 16:54:39 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: fuxiuyin
16/10/28 16:54:39 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
16/10/28 16:54:39 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
16/10/28 16:54:39 INFO spark.SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(fuxiuyin); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(fuxiuyin); groups with modify permissions: Set()
16/10/28 16:54:39 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 42519.
16/10/28 16:54:39 INFO spark.SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
16/10/28 16:54:39 INFO spark.SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
16/10/28 16:54:39 INFO storage.DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /opt/spark/blockmgr-1dcd1d1a-4cf4-4778-9b71-53e238a62c97
16/10/28 16:54:39 INFO memory.MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 366.3 MB
16/10/28 16:54:40 INFO spark.SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
16/10/28 16:54:40 INFO util.log: Logging initialized @1843ms
16/10/28 16:54:40 INFO server.Server: jetty-9.2.z-SNAPSHOT
16/10/28 16:54:40 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@1b933891{/jobs,null,AVAILABLE}
16/10/28 16:54:40 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@580d9060{/jobs/json,null,AVAILABLE}
16/10/28 16:54:40 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@3a8fb3d9{/jobs/job,null,AVAILABLE}
16/10/28 16:54:40 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@744ecb1b{/jobs/job/json,null,AVAILABLE}
16/10/28 16:54:40 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@761b32b3{/stages,null,AVAILABLE}
16/10/28 16:54:40 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@42213280{/stages/json,null,AVAILABLE}
16/10/28 16:54:40 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@5775066{/stages/stage,null,AVAILABLE}
16/10/28 16:54:40 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@7e355c0{/stages/stage/json,null,AVAILABLE}
16/10/28 16:54:40 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@28426125{/stages/pool,null,AVAILABLE}
16/10/28 16:54:40 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@63bcf39f{/stages/pool/json,null,AVAILABLE}
16/10/28 16:54:40 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@5cf77bee{/storage,null,AVAILABLE}
16/10/28 16:54:40 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@412768e5{/storage/json,null,AVAILABLE}
16/10/28 16:54:40 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@7ad772ad{/storage/rdd,null,AVAILABLE}
16/10/28 16:54:40 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@7ef35663{/storage/rdd/json,null,AVAILABLE}
16/10/28 16:54:40 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@193c7a58{/environment,null,AVAILABLE}
16/10/28 16:54:40 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@63a649da{/environment/json,null,AVAILABLE}
16/10/28 16:54:40 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@22251d19{/executors,null,AVAILABLE}
16/10/28 16:54:40 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@46810770{/executors/json,null,AVAILABLE}
16/10/28 16:54:40 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@3c155b42{/executors/threadDump,null,AVAILABLE}
16/10/28 16:54:40 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@6dac2d83{/executors/threadDump/json,null,AVAILABLE}
16/10/28 16:54:40 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@67eb38fa{/static,null,AVAILABLE}
16/10/28 16:54:40 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@291f19f0{/,null,AVAILABLE}
16/10/28 16:54:40 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@3f4688da{/api,null,AVAILABLE}
16/10/28 16:54:40 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@338a7a84{/stages/stage/kill,null,AVAILABLE}
16/10/28 16:54:40 INFO server.ServerConnector: Started ServerConnector@7df0e73{HTTP/1.1}{fuxiuyin-virtual-machine:4040}
16/10/28 16:54:40 INFO server.Server: Started @1962ms
16/10/28 16:54:40 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
16/10/28 16:54:40 INFO ui.SparkUI: Bound SparkUI to fuxiuyin-virtual-machine, and started at http://192.168.102.133:4040
16/10/28 16:54:40 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at fuxiuyin-virtual-machine/192.168.102.133:8032
16/10/28 16:54:41 INFO yarn.Client: Requesting a new application from cluster with 1 NodeManagers
16/10/28 16:54:41 INFO yarn.Client: Verifying our application has not requested more than the maximum memory capability of the cluster (8192 MB per container)
16/10/28 16:54:41 INFO yarn.Client: Will allocate AM container, with 896 MB memory including 384 MB overhead
16/10/28 16:54:41 INFO yarn.Client: Setting up container launch context for our AM
16/10/28 16:54:41 INFO yarn.Client: Setting up the launch environment for our AM container
16/10/28 16:54:41 INFO yarn.Client: Preparing resources for our AM container
16/10/28 16:54:41 WARN yarn.Client: Neither spark.yarn.jars nor spark.yarn.archive is set, falling back to uploading libraries under SPARK_HOME.
16/10/28 16:54:42 INFO yarn.Client: Uploading resource file:/opt/spark/spark-97ecc15d-7f26-4b73-a67e-953fdc127898/__spark_libs__697818607740390689.zip -> hdfs://fuxiuyin-virtual-machine:9000/user/fuxiuyin/.sparkStaging/application_1477644823180_0001/__spark_libs__697818607740390689.zip
16/10/28 16:54:45 INFO yarn.Client: Uploading resource file:/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip -> hdfs://fuxiuyin-virtual-machine:9000/user/fuxiuyin/.sparkStaging/application_1477644823180_0001/pyspark.zip
16/10/28 16:54:45 INFO yarn.Client: Uploading resource file:/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.3-src.zip -> hdfs://fuxiuyin-virtual-machine:9000/user/fuxiuyin/.sparkStaging/application_1477644823180_0001/py4j-0.10.3-src.zip
16/10/28 16:54:45 INFO yarn.Client: Uploading resource file:/opt/spark/spark-97ecc15d-7f26-4b73-a67e-953fdc127898/__spark_conf__7760765070208746118.zip -> hdfs://fuxiuyin-virtual-machine:9000/user/fuxiuyin/.sparkStaging/application_1477644823180_0001/__spark_conf__.zip
16/10/28 16:54:45 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: fuxiuyin
16/10/28 16:54:45 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: fuxiuyin
16/10/28 16:54:45 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
16/10/28 16:54:45 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
16/10/28 16:54:45 INFO spark.SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(fuxiuyin); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(fuxiuyin); groups with modify permissions: Set()
16/10/28 16:54:45 INFO yarn.Client: Submitting application application_1477644823180_0001 to ResourceManager
16/10/28 16:54:45 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1477644823180_0001
16/10/28 16:54:45 INFO cluster.SchedulerExtensionServices: Starting Yarn extension services with app application_1477644823180_0001 and attemptId None
16/10/28 16:54:46 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1477644823180_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/10/28 16:54:46 INFO yarn.Client: 
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: N/A
     ApplicationMaster host: N/A
     ApplicationMaster RPC port: -1
     queue: default
     start time: 1477644885891
     final status: UNDEFINED
     tracking URL: http://fuxiuyin-virtual-machine:8088/proxy/application_1477644823180_0001/
     user: fuxiuyin
16/10/28 16:54:47 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1477644823180_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/10/28 16:54:48 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1477644823180_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/10/28 16:54:49 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1477644823180_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/10/28 16:54:50 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1477644823180_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/10/28 16:54:51 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1477644823180_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/10/28 16:54:52 INFO cluster.YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: ApplicationMaster registered as NettyRpcEndpointRef(null)
16/10/28 16:54:52 INFO cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Add WebUI Filter. org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter, Map(PROXY_HOSTS -> fuxiuyin-virtual-machine, PROXY_URI_BASES -> http://fuxiuyin-virtual-machine:8088/proxy/application_1477644823180_0001), /proxy/application_1477644823180_0001
16/10/28 16:54:52 INFO ui.JettyUtils: Adding filter: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter
16/10/28 16:54:52 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1477644823180_0001 (state: RUNNING)
16/10/28 16:54:52 INFO yarn.Client: 
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: N/A
     ApplicationMaster host: 192.168.102.133
     ApplicationMaster RPC port: 0
     queue: default
     start time: 1477644885891
     final status: UNDEFINED
     tracking URL: http://fuxiuyin-virtual-machine:8088/proxy/application_1477644823180_0001/
     user: fuxiuyin
16/10/28 16:54:52 INFO cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Application application_1477644823180_0001 has started running.
16/10/28 16:54:52 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 39951.
16/10/28 16:54:52 INFO netty.NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 192.168.102.133:39951
16/10/28 16:54:53 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Registering BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.102.133, 39951)
16/10/28 16:54:53 INFO storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 192.168.102.133:39951 with 366.3 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.102.133, 39951)
16/10/28 16:54:53 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.102.133, 39951)
16/10/28 16:54:53 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@43ba5458{/metrics/json,null,AVAILABLE}
16/10/28 16:54:57 INFO cluster.YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: ApplicationMaster registered as NettyRpcEndpointRef(null)
16/10/28 16:54:57 INFO cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Add WebUI Filter. org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter, Map(PROXY_HOSTS -> fuxiuyin-virtual-machine, PROXY_URI_BASES -> http://fuxiuyin-virtual-machine:8088/proxy/application_1477644823180_0001), /proxy/application_1477644823180_0001
16/10/28 16:54:57 INFO ui.JettyUtils: Adding filter: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter
16/10/28 16:54:59 INFO cluster.YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnDriverEndpoint: Registered executor NettyRpcEndpointRef(null) (192.168.102.133:45708) with ID 1
16/10/28 16:54:59 INFO storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager fuxiuyin-virtual-machine:33074 with 366.3 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(1, fuxiuyin-virtual-machine, 33074)
16/10/28 16:55:00 INFO cluster.YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnDriverEndpoint: Registered executor NettyRpcEndpointRef(null) (192.168.102.133:45712) with ID 2
16/10/28 16:55:00 INFO cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: SchedulerBackend is ready for scheduling beginning after reached minRegisteredResourcesRatio: 0.8
16/10/28 16:55:00 INFO storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager fuxiuyin-virtual-machine:43740 with 366.3 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(2, fuxiuyin-virtual-machine, 43740)
16/10/28 16:55:00 INFO spark.SparkContext: Starting job: collect at /home/fuxiuyin/test_app.py:8
16/10/28 16:55:00 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Got job 0 (collect at /home/fuxiuyin/test_app.py:8) with 2 output partitions
16/10/28 16:55:00 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 0 (collect at /home/fuxiuyin/test_app.py:8)
16/10/28 16:55:00 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
16/10/28 16:55:00 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
16/10/28 16:55:00 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 0 (PythonRDD[1] at collect at /home/fuxiuyin/test_app.py:8), which has no missing parents
16/10/28 16:55:00 INFO memory.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 3.8 KB, free 366.3 MB)
16/10/28 16:55:00 INFO memory.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 2.5 KB, free 366.3 MB)
16/10/28 16:55:00 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on 192.168.102.133:39951 (size: 2.5 KB, free: 366.3 MB)
16/10/28 16:55:00 INFO spark.SparkContext: Created broadcast 0 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1012
16/10/28 16:55:00 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Submitting 2 missing tasks from ResultStage 0 (PythonRDD[1] at collect at /home/fuxiuyin/test_app.py:8)
16/10/28 16:55:00 INFO cluster.YarnScheduler: Adding task set 0.0 with 2 tasks
16/10/28 16:55:00 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, fuxiuyin-virtual-machine, partition 0, PROCESS_LOCAL, 5450 bytes)
16/10/28 16:55:00 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1, fuxiuyin-virtual-machine, partition 1, PROCESS_LOCAL, 5469 bytes)
16/10/28 16:55:00 INFO cluster.YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnDriverEndpoint: Launching task 0 on executor id: 2 hostname: fuxiuyin-virtual-machine.
16/10/28 16:55:00 INFO cluster.YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnDriverEndpoint: Launching task 1 on executor id: 1 hostname: fuxiuyin-virtual-machine.
16/10/28 16:55:01 ERROR cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Yarn application has already exited with state FINISHED!
16/10/28 16:55:01 INFO server.ServerConnector: Stopped ServerConnector@7df0e73{HTTP/1.1}{fuxiuyin-virtual-machine:4040}
16/10/28 16:55:01 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@338a7a84{/stages/stage/kill,null,UNAVAILABLE}
16/10/28 16:55:01 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@3f4688da{/api,null,UNAVAILABLE}
16/10/28 16:55:01 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@291f19f0{/,null,UNAVAILABLE}
16/10/28 16:55:01 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@67eb38fa{/static,null,UNAVAILABLE}
16/10/28 16:55:01 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@6dac2d83{/executors/threadDump/json,null,UNAVAILABLE}
16/10/28 16:55:01 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@3c155b42{/executors/threadDump,null,UNAVAILABLE}
16/10/28 16:55:01 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@46810770{/executors/json,null,UNAVAILABLE}
16/10/28 16:55:01 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@22251d19{/executors,null,UNAVAILABLE}
16/10/28 16:55:01 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@63a649da{/environment/json,null,UNAVAILABLE}
16/10/28 16:55:01 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@193c7a58{/environment,null,UNAVAILABLE}
16/10/28 16:55:01 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@7ef35663{/storage/rdd/json,null,UNAVAILABLE}
16/10/28 16:55:01 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@7ad772ad{/storage/rdd,null,UNAVAILABLE}
16/10/28 16:55:01 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@412768e5{/storage/json,null,UNAVAILABLE}
16/10/28 16:55:01 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@5cf77bee{/storage,null,UNAVAILABLE}
16/10/28 16:55:01 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@63bcf39f{/stages/pool/json,null,UNAVAILABLE}
16/10/28 16:55:01 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@28426125{/stages/pool,null,UNAVAILABLE}
16/10/28 16:55:01 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@7e355c0{/stages/stage/json,null,UNAVAILABLE}
16/10/28 16:55:01 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@5775066{/stages/stage,null,UNAVAILABLE}
16/10/28 16:55:01 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@42213280{/stages/json,null,UNAVAILABLE}
16/10/28 16:55:01 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@761b32b3{/stages,null,UNAVAILABLE}
16/10/28 16:55:01 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@744ecb1b{/jobs/job/json,null,UNAVAILABLE}
16/10/28 16:55:01 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@3a8fb3d9{/jobs/job,null,UNAVAILABLE}
16/10/28 16:55:01 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@580d9060{/jobs/json,null,UNAVAILABLE}
16/10/28 16:55:01 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@1b933891{/jobs,null,UNAVAILABLE}
16/10/28 16:55:01 INFO ui.SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://192.168.102.133:4040
16/10/28 16:55:01 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Job 0 failed: collect at /home/fuxiuyin/test_app.py:8, took 0.383872 s
16/10/28 16:55:01 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: ResultStage 0 (collect at /home/fuxiuyin/test_app.py:8) failed in 0.233 s
16/10/28 16:55:01 ERROR scheduler.LiveListenerBus: SparkListenerBus has already stopped! Dropping event SparkListenerStageCompleted(org.apache.spark.scheduler.StageInfo@469337f1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fuxiuyin/test_app.py", line 8, in <module>
    print(data.collect())
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 776, in collect
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.3-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.3-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError16/10/28 16:55:01 ERROR scheduler.LiveListenerBus: SparkListenerBus has already stopped! Dropping event SparkListenerJobEnd(0,1477644901073,JobFailed(org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job 0 cancelled because SparkContext was shut down))
: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job 0 cancelled because SparkContext was shut down
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$cleanUpAfterSchedulerStop$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:818)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$cleanUpAfterSchedulerStop$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:816)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashSet.foreach(HashSet.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.cleanUpAfterSchedulerStop(DAGScheduler.scala:816)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onStop(DAGScheduler.scala:1685)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop.stop(EventLoop.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.stop(DAGScheduler.scala:1604)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$stop$8.apply$mcV$sp(SparkContext.scala:1798)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryLogNonFatalError(Utils.scala:1287)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.stop(SparkContext.scala:1797)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend$MonitorThread.run(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:632)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1890)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1903)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1916)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1930)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:912)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:358)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:911)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:453)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:237)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

16/10/28 16:55:01 ERROR client.TransportClient: Failed to send RPC 9187551343857476032 to /192.168.102.133:45698: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
16/10/28 16:55:01 ERROR cluster.YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: Sending RequestExecutors(0,0,Map()) to AM was unsuccessful
java.io.IOException: Failed to send RPC 9187551343857476032 to /192.168.102.133:45698: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClient$3.operationComplete(TransportClient.java:249)
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClient$3.operationComplete(TransportClient.java:233)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:680)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise$LateListeners.run(DefaultPromise.java:845)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise$LateListenerNotifier.run(DefaultPromise.java:873)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:357)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
16/10/28 16:55:01 INFO cluster.SchedulerExtensionServices: Stopping SchedulerExtensionServices
(serviceOption=None,
 services=List(),
 started=false)
16/10/28 16:55:01 ERROR util.Utils: Uncaught exception in thread Yarn application state monitor
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:59)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.apply(PartialFunction.scala:167)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend.requestTotalExecutors(CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend.scala:508)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnSchedulerBackend.stop(YarnSchedulerBackend.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.stop(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.stop(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:455)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.stop(DAGScheduler.scala:1605)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$stop$8.apply$mcV$sp(SparkContext.scala:1798)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryLogNonFatalError(Utils.scala:1287)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.stop(SparkContext.scala:1797)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend$MonitorThread.run(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:108)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to send RPC 9187551343857476032 to /192.168.102.133:45698: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClient$3.operationComplete(TransportClient.java:249)
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClient$3.operationComplete(TransportClient.java:233)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:680)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise$LateListeners.run(DefaultPromise.java:845)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise$LateListenerNotifier.run(DefaultPromise.java:873)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:357)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
16/10/28 16:55:01 INFO spark.MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
16/10/28 16:55:01 INFO storage.DiskBlockManager: Shutdown hook called
16/10/28 16:55:01 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
16/10/28 16:55:01 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /opt/spark/spark-97ecc15d-7f26-4b73-a67e-953fdc127898/userFiles-f51df2cd-8ec0-4caa-862f-77db0cc72505
16/10/28 16:55:01 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /opt/spark/spark-97ecc15d-7f26-4b73-a67e-953fdc127898/pyspark-5216f977-d3c3-495f-b91a-88fa2218696d
16/10/28 16:55:01 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /opt/spark/spark-97ecc15d-7f26-4b73-a67e-953fdc127898
16/10/28 16:55:01 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on fuxiuyin-virtual-machine:43740 (size: 2.5 KB, free: 366.3 MB)
16/10/28 16:55:01 ERROR scheduler.LiveListenerBus: SparkListenerBus has already stopped! Dropping event SparkListenerBlockUpdated(BlockUpdatedInfo(BlockManagerId(2, fuxiuyin-virtual-machine, 43740),broadcast_0_piece0,StorageLevel(memory, 1 replicas),2517,0))
16/10/28 16:55:01 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on fuxiuyin-virtual-machine:33074 (size: 2.5 KB, free: 366.3 MB)
16/10/28 16:55:01 ERROR scheduler.LiveListenerBus: SparkListenerBus has already stopped! Dropping event SparkListenerBlockUpdated(BlockUpdatedInfo(BlockManagerId(1, fuxiuyin-virtual-machine, 33074),broadcast_0_piece0,StorageLevel(memory, 1 replicas),2517,0))
16/10/28 16:55:01 INFO memory.MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
16/10/28 16:55:01 INFO storage.BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
```

And the log of yarn resourcemanager is in

[yarn-fuxiuyin-resourcemanager-fuxiuyin-virtual-machine.log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ffl2sh4hepy5lu5/yarn-fuxiuyin-resourcemanager-fuxiuyin-virtual-machine.log?dl=0)

I submit app by this user:

```
uid=1000(fuxiuyin) gid=1000(fuxiuyin) 组=1000(fuxiuyin),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),108(lpadmin),124(sambashare)
```

My test_app is

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf

conf = SparkConf().setAppName("test_app")

sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
data = sc.parallelize([1, 2, 3])
data = data.map(lambda x: x + 1)
print(data.collect())
```

I don't how to fix it.

Thinks.

Comment: Hello, what user are you using to launch this application, and what is its ID ? (type id in your terminal).

Comment: please upload the code segment where you initialise the contexts.

Comment: @KamalPradhan Ok, I added the code of my test app.

Answer (score 0):

The driver has to collect all the data from worker nodes before printing so use the code below..

> **i think the error is due to**

```
print(data.collect())
```

use

```
for x in data.collect():
       print x
```

and use spark submit as:

```
spark-submit --master yarn deploy-mode cluster test_app.py
```

Comment: I change my code to this, but it also can't run. There must be some problem in yarn, because my test_app can run in spark standalone mode.

Comment: is the cluster is managed by ambari or it is managed manually.

Comment: The app can run successfully if i use `/opt/spark/bin/spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster test_app.py`. But it don't work when I use `--deploy-mode client`.

Comment: Thats because you are submitting application to yarn cluster not yarn client. your driver program is running on the yarn client where you type the command to submit the spark application (may not be a machine in the yarn cluster). In this mode, although the drive program is running on the client machine, the tasks are executed on the executors in the node managers of the YARN cluster.

Comment: It means I must submit my app use cluster deploy-mode?

Comment: Yes you should deploy the app in yarn cluster model

Comment: @KamalPradhan What is the difference in terms of discussed error whether the cluster is managed by Ambari vs manually?

Answer (score 0):

instead of `spark-submit --master yarn test_app.py`
try this command `spark-submit --master yarn-client test_app.py`